# Proof that if Wronskian is nonzero

Tags: proof-writing

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be real functions whose Wronskian is nonzero. Suppose that $Ay_1 + By_2= 0$. Prove that $A=B=0$

---

I have proved that $y_1, y_2 \neq 0$, if $A = 0 \rightarrow B =0$, and if $B = 0 \rightarrow A = 0$.
However, how do I complete the proof by showing that both $A,B$ have to be zero. (i.e. can't be non-zero?)

Comment: Take a derivative of your equality. Get a system of linear equations with unknown $A, B$. Use Kramer rule to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\neq 0$ then $y_1=-\frac  B A y_2$ and you can see (from the definition of Wronskian) ) that the Wronskian) is $0$ in this case.  [The first column is $-\frac B A$ times the second column, so the determinant is $0$]. Hence, $A=0$. Similarly, $B=0$.

Comment: so are you plugging in $(-B/A)y_2$ and $(-A/B)y_1$ into the wronskian

Comment: Put $y_1=-\frac  B A y_2$ and $y'_1=-\frac  B A y'_2$ in the definition of the Wronskian @rabito

Comment: when computing I get $y_2y_1' - y_2'y_1$ which doesn't equal zero

Comment: You did not substitute for $y_1$ in terms of $y_2$. $\det \left[\begin{array}{llll} {-\frac  B A y_2} & {y_2}  \\ {-\frac  B A y'_2} & {y'_2}   \end{array}\right]=0$ @rabito